# How to use shared preference in flutter with dynamic forms

Tags: flutter, dart

in my app i am generating forms dynamically, i want to store every form data to be stored locally so that i can use it in my app. i also want the form textfield to be filled autometically with the previous data the user has entered with initstate but i am unable to implemet it.

i am expecting to store each form data locally, to use that later.
secondly i want the form fields to be filled when the app is opened with the data that user has entered previously.
[image]

Comment: SharedPreferences is a key-value store. You could use a map to store data about each user or use Hive/ Isar database to store a custom User class.

Comment: Sharedpreference is not designed to be used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more practical for you to generate a JSON from this form. This way it will save and retrieve only a single field. When retrieving the JSON you get a MAP there it's easy to find the field and restore its value. But, use it in moderation, pay attention to the limitations of the package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).